# How to use different Color Theme in Ms word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, color-theme

I have a document with 3 pages, in each page I have a table for which I want to use I different color theme.

In MS Word 365 I go to `Design` menu and then option `Colors` and select desired color theme. This is different than `Table design` menu which gives completely different results and styles, but not the desired ones.

[image]

The issue is that when I select a color theme, the the theme is applied to the whole document and not only the table I have selected.

How can I use color themes for specific tables avoiding to applied it to whole document? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The themes you are referring to are *Document* themes. They change anything linked to a theme in the document. You cannot use them for parts of a document.

There are also **Table Styles** available which could be used to change how different tables work. *Note, since table styles use the Normal paragraph style, changes to that style can change the appearance of tables. That style is tied to the document theme.*

Table Styles can be found on the Table Design tab. That tab is contextual; it appears when you are in a Table. In earlier versions it was simply a second "Design" tab under Table Tools.

[image: Table Styles as shown on the Microsoft site]

Comment: Thanks Charles for your answer. So, the most I can do would be try to set different styles similar to those options available in built in themes to apply separately to each table?

Comment: Not exactly. There are Table Styles. These are styles for the entire table. Here is the Word announcement on these. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/08/30/working-with-tables-in-the-new-word/ --- I've amended my answer to add a picture of the built-in table styles. You can create your own Table Styles as well.

Comment: Like many galleries in Word, when you mouse over these, you will see what changes it would make in your table.

Comment: Thanks Charles for your help and time. I´ll try as you mention. Regards